# Laravel REST API Design

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

I am building a Laravel application with a Vue front end and Laravel API back end.

I have been following REST guidelines and have created the following end points for retrieving documents:

```
// Documents
Route::prefix('documents')->name('documents.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [DocumentController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    Route::get('/{document}', [DocumentController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
    Route::post('/', [DocumentController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::put('/{document}', [DocumentController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
    Route::delete('/{document}', [DocumentController::class, 'delete'])->name('delete');
});
```

The documents table has a user_id column and I want an end point that returns only documents for a user. How should this be done in a REST manner?

I can add another end point like this:

```
Route::get('/{user}', [DocumentController::class, 'getByUser'])->name('getByUser');
```

Or do I add an optional query parameter to the index endpoint?

```
Route::get('/{?user}', [DocumentController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
```

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: This might be opinionated, but for me, the most logical endpoint would be `/users/{user}/documents`. For a route like `/documents/{some-id}` I would expect that id to be a document id.

Comment: The suggestion by @rickdenhaan (`users/{user}/documents`) is logical and a common convention. Something I would suggest though is that you don't add a custom method `getByUser` to your existing `DocumentController` and instead create another controller for encapsulating that logic (either nested or named `UserDocumentContoller` for example). It is not essential but does provide clean separation and encapsulation and keeps the `HTTP` `verbs` mapped to standard actions.

Comment: Is there ever an instance where every single document (for all users) needs to be retrieved? If yes, then I would go with what the others have said, but if no, then your routes now are perfectly fine.